# jQuery form validation ( if == "" do this) only works on first input

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, if-statement

I have a form which I'm using jQuery to validate that the inputs aren't empty. (I'm using bootstrap too)

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <div id="name_input" class="form-group">
    <input id="name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback name_span></span>
  </div>
  <div id="email_input" class="form-group">
    <input id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback email_span></span>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="save">
</form>
```

with jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.form-control-feedback').hide();
  $(".submit").click(function() {
    var name = $("#name").val();
    if (name == "") {
      $("#name_input").addClass("has-error has-feedback");
      $(".name_span").show();
      return false;
    }
    var email = $("#email").val();
    if (email == "") {
      $("#email_input").addClass("has-error has-feedback");
      $(".email_span").show();
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

when I use this code and both inputs are empty, the classes "has-error" and "has-feedback" only append to the first input.

if the first input is filled in and the second is empty the classes adds to the second one, and if I empty the first one too that one also get the classes.

but if I do the other way around, so the first is empty first and the secound input is empty after, the classes still only add to the first one.

Also when I fill one of them in, I want to removeClass but I can't do that with:

```
} else {
   $("#name_input").removeClass("has-error has-feedback");
   $(".name_span").hide();
}
```

since that will submit the form and obvious I can't add `return false;` since that will prevent the form to process even if it's filled in... Any suggestions on these?

Comment: "if the first input is filled in and the second is empty the classes adds to the second one, and if I empty the first one too that one also get the classes."  To change that you need to reset the fields before you rerun the check.

Comment: Instead of returning false after every check you probably want to just set a flag and then check it at the end.

Comment: @nurdyguy but that's not a problem, if both are empty I want both to have an error, but I think you mean that if I fill in the empty one and then erase the filled one?

Comment: @j08691 you're more than welcome to make an answer with that, since I don't exactly know what you mean or how to do that

Comment: Seems like a couple of others have gone ahead and done that :)

Comment: Well, if both are empty only the first will be detected because you have return false;

Comment: @j08691 yes I saw that when I refreshed the page! I was like 'HOLY, that escalated quickly'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `return` statement immediately stops executing a function. So this code here

```
if (name == "") {
  $("#name_input").addClass("has-error has-feedback");
  $(".name_span").show();
  return false;
}
var email = $("#email").val();
if (email == "") {
  $("#email_input").addClass("has-error has-feedback");
  $(".email_span").show();
  return false;
}
```

Says that if `name == ""` , don't even evaluate the email. Instead, you may want to use a flag to see if any errors occurred.

```
var dataIsValid = true;
var name = $("#name").val();
if (name == "") {
  $("#name_input").addClass("has-error has-feedback");
  $(".name_span").show();
  dataIsValid = false;
}
var email = $("#email").val();
if (email == "") {
  $("#email_input").addClass("has-error has-feedback");
  $(".email_span").show();
  dataIsValid = false;
}

return dataIsValid;
```

As @imvain2 pointed out, you'll also want to remove the error classes. Otherwise, as soon as you get an error once, it will always look like they have an error.

```
var dataIsValid = true;
var name = $("#name").val();
if (name == "") {
  $("#name_input").addClass("has-error has-feedback");
  $(".name_span").show();
  dataIsValid = false;
} else { // Valid, remove the error classes
  $("#name_input").removeClass("has-error has-feedback");
  $(".name_span").hide();
}

var email = $("#email").val();
if (email == "") {
  $("#email_input").addClass("has-error has-feedback");
  $(".email_span").show();
  dataIsValid = false;
} else { // Valid, remove the error classes
  $("#email_input").removeClass("has-error has-feedback");
  $(".email_span").hide();
}

return dataIsValid;
```

Comment: also before the if statements, remove the classes and hide the error div:  `$("#name_input").removeClass("has-error has-feedback"); $(".name_span").hide();$("#email_input").removeClass("has-error has-feedback"); $(".email_span").hide();`

Comment: @imvain2 Thanks, good point. Edited to include that information.

Comment: the spans are hidden with the '`$('.form-control-feedback').hide();` and the inputs don't have the classes `has-error has-feedback` from the beginning :) ut I will try this! Thank you!

Comment: @Pixeldoris Well that's convenient! And removing the classes every time just makes sure that they won't be there no matter what when the fields are valid. Hope this all helped.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning on the first error. If you want to list through each you need to remove the individual return statements.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.form-control-feedback').hide();
  $(".submit").click(function() {
    var name = $("#name").val(),
        errorMsg = [];

    if (name == "") {
      $("#name_input").addClass("has-error has-feedback");
      $(".name_span").show();
      errorMsg.push('Invalid Name');
    }
    var email = $("#email").val();
    if (email == "") {
      $("#email_input").addClass("has-error has-feedback");
      $(".email_span").show();
      errorMsg.push('Invalid Email');
    }
    if (errorMsg.length > 0 ){
       // alert('Errors:\n' + errMsg.join('\n'));
       return false;
    }
  });
});
```